# SQL or noSQL database for large data imports and fast lookups?

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, nosql

I want to:

- read a few 100 GB from csv files > convert some columns to a specific format > save to DB. This should be run a few times a day.
- query the DB with 4 parameters and order the results by an attribute (eg PRICE ASC), then pick the TOP entry.

Postgres performs fine in general, means: 1-2 GB / min (using java).
Also selects are quite fine when I put an `index` on my 4 paramters that are used for the select.

Still, it will take a "long" time when importing a few hundred GBs.

Question: could it be worthwhile to try the same using a `noSQL` engine like `apache Cassandra`?
I mean:

- could a noSQL DB be faster for mass inserts of data
- can I retrieve a row from noSQL based on a few parameters as quick as in an indexed postgres db?

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you simply try it and measure.  I'm thinking that the transfer rate is determined by the network speed, not the persistence mechanism.  My guess?  No difference at all.

Comment: Why is your import slow? What part of your proces doesn't perform well? And how do you save to DB? Single INSERT's are slow, multi INSERT's within a single transaction are faster, and COPY can be very fast.

Comment: I'm using `COPY FROM STDIN ... CSV`. The bottleneck is the database, I hardly need any time for processing. I'm importing to an `UNLOGGED` table without `indexes`. I think 2GB/min batching to postgres is not a bad performance at all. But I hoped maybe migrating to noSQL might make my import much faster than postgres?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra builds on query driven modelling. Since you know your query (and assuming you want equality checks for the four params), you should be able to get blistering query speeds if you model the data right.

Cassandra ingestion is also very fast. However, if you've got a lot of data, the usual approach is to transform that data to SSTables (possibly via some code) and import (which is extremely fast). If that's not feasible, you can do parallel async rights.

COPY is not really meant for large scale production usage. Either write an importer that uses the java client to do async writes with futures, or go the SSTable route. Another good alternative is to use Spark and the Spark Cassandra connector to forward CSV rdds to a cassandra table. Of course, you'll need a spark cluster for that to work (though depending on machine power / load you might get away with a single node spark standalone process - in which case what you gain is the simplicity). The spark code would look like:

`sc.textFile("csv.csv").split(",").[...transforms..].saveToCassandra('ks', 'table');`